# The difference between "当たり" and "につき" in terms of the meaning "every ~"

Tags: usage

As mentioned at the title, I would like to ask the if there is any difference or nuance between "当たり" and "につき" in terms of the meaning "every ~". Any case that they cannot be used interchangeably?

For instance, do the following sentences (if they are grammatically correct) convey the exact same meaning?

> 卵は一人**につき**二つまで　　　＝　　卵は一人**あたり**二つまで
>
> 一ヶ月**につき**一回東京へ行く　＝　　一ヶ月**あたり**一回東京へ行く

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[There is a page](http://naniga-chigauno.st042.net/z425.html) that tries to describe the difference, but につき and あたり(の) seemed interchangeable to me for all the examples in the page :) So I think the difference is very small and they are basically interchangeable. Still, there are small differences:

- ～につき sounds more formal and stiff.
- ～あたり tends to be used in relation to a total amount. In other words, if you did a mathematical division in your mind, ～あたり may be used more often. If I heard 1か月あたり1回(東京へ行く) instead of 毎月 or 月に1回, I may feel you have a big project in Tokyo.